In a connected compact Hausdorff space two disjoint non-empty closed sets are "joined" by a connected set
This is Exercise 16 of §4 of Chapter 2 of Bourbaki's General Topology. The proof sketched in the hints is quite involved and I can't manage to fill in the details. It's also hard to explain where I'm stuck in a self-contained way. I've tried to do so in question 2 and below, but an answer to question 1 would already be more than sufficient.

Main Statement
Let $X$ be a connected compact Hausdorff space and let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint non-empty closed subsets of $X$. Then there is a component of $X\backslash(A\cup B)$ whose closure meets both $A$ and $B$.

(Obviously, it is equivalent to show that there exists a connected subset of $X\backslash(A\cup B)$ whose closure meets both $A$ and $B$.)
Question 1 (my main hope): Does someone know a published proof of the statement or a weaker version of it?
Question 2 (a long shot): Can you help me prove the first (and probably hardest) step:

Step: For all entourages $U$ of $X$ with $U^2(A)\cap U^2(B)=\emptyset$, there is a component of $X\backslash\big(U(A)\cup U(B)\big)$ that meets both $\overline{U(A)}$ and $\overline{U(B)}$.

(It should be enough to do so for a base of entourages, so you can assume that $U$ is symmetric, open, etc. if it helps.)
Bourbaki says to use the following lemma (another exercise):

Lemma: Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then the space $\mathfrak{F}(X)$ of non-empty closed subsets of $X$, with the Vietoris topology, is compact. Consider an ultrafilter $\Psi$ on $\mathfrak{F}(X)$, and suppose that for each entourage $V$ and each $\mathfrak{X}\in\Psi$ there exists $M\in\mathfrak{X}$ such that any two points of $M$ can be joined by a $V$-chain contained in $M$. Then the limit point of $\Psi$ in $\mathfrak{F}(X)$ is connected.

The idea seems to be to start off with $W$-chains joining $U(A)$ and $U(B)$, where $W\subset U$ is a symmetric entourage, and in some sense take the limit for $W$ becoming arbitrarily small to get an actually connected set joining $U(A)$ and $U(B)$. This "taking the limit" has to formalized by defining a suitable filter on $\mathfrak{F}(X)$, probably invoking the ultrafilter lemma, and then applying the lemma above.
But I have no idea how to define the filter such that it works. It seems natural to define a filter base in the form of a family $(\mathcal{S}_W)$, where the $W$ are the symmetric entourages contained in $U$, such that $\mathcal{S}_W$ contains some or all $W$-chains connecting $W\big(U(A)\big)$ and $W\big(U(B)\big)$. But the condition in the lemma ("there exists $M$...") would suggest that every element of the filter has to contain chains of arbitrary closeness.

Explanation of non-standard terminology
A compact Hausdorff space is canonically a uniform space by taking as entourages the neighbourhoods of the diagonal in $X\times X$. For a symmetric entourage $V$, two points $x,y\in X$ are said to be $V$-close if $(x,y)\in V$, and a $V$-chain is a finite sequence of points where every point is $V$-close to its successor. For a set $A\subset X$, the term $V(A)$ denotes the set of points which are $V$-close to a point of $A$.
If you're not familiar with uniform spaces, you can make the additional assumption that $X$ is a metric space and only consider entourages of the form $\{(x,y)\in X\times X:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$.
$\mathfrak{F}(X)$, the space of non-empty closed subsets of $X$, with the Vietoris (aka hyperspace) topology is also canonically a uniform space, and the set of $\widetilde{V}$, with $V$ a symmetric entourage of $X$, is a base of entourages, where
$$
\widetilde{V}:=\big\{(A,B)\in\mathfrak{F}(X)\times\mathfrak{F}(X):A\subset V(B)\text{ and }B\subset V(B)\big\}.
$$
In the metric space case, it is induced by the Hausdorff metric, see here.

This is a very interesting question. Indeed, the question just relies on the definition of connected spaces, that is, could have been proposed as an exercise in Chapter 1 of Bourbaki's General Topology. However, the solution proposed by Bourbaki relies on uniform spaces, which is a bit surprising, in my opinion. I wonder whether it is possible to avoid them.
